# scp from a first computer to second computer to send something to a third computer

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a bash script that I use on a supercomputer (CentOS). This computer is setup such that there is a single node that has internet access (call it "**connectedNode**")-- and through this node, all the other nodes (call them "**workNodes**") can be accessed. Most of the work is done after ssh-ing through the **connectedNode** to a **workNode**.

I have a bash script which is essentially this one liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
# scpdropbox
scp $1 myusername@desktop:/Users/myusername/Dropbox/Inbox
```

that allows me to run a command like:

```
scpdropbox file.name
```

and because I've setup ssh-keys between all of the nodes and my external computer (**desktop**) I want this file to end up on, it works great. Of course, this only works if I'm running it from the **connectedNode**, otherwise, this command fails, as the **workNodes** aren't connected to the internet.

How do I modify this script so that I could run this command from a **workNode**, and have it send the correct files and whatnot through the **connectedNode** and on to the **desktop**?

Things I've tried so far (commented out):

```
PWD=$(pwd)

# ssh myusername@connectedNode <<'ENDSSH'
# ssh -t myusername@connectedNode <<'ENDSSH'
ssh -t -t myusername@connectedNode <<'ENDSSH'
#commands to run on remote host
# scp \$PWD/\$1 myusername@desktop:/Users/myusername/Dropbox/Inbox
# scp '$PWD'/'$1' myusername@desktop:/Users/myusername/Dropbox/Inbox
scp $PWD/$1 myusername@desktop:/Users/myusername/Dropbox/Inbox
ENDSSH
```

And they don't work. I get errors like:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
/home/dir/myusername: not a regular file
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

depending on which of the things I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each of your worknodes, add something like the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
host desktop
   ProxyCommand ssh -xaqW%h:22 myusername@connectedNode
```

Now, when a worknode tries to ssh to desktop, it will first connect to `myusername@connectedNode`, then continue the SSH to desktop (`%h`) port 22.

I use this to allow my workstation at work, with no Internet or default route, to connect to external hosts through another machine on the network that does have network access on another network interface.  Works like a charm.

Note that if you're using a very old `ssh` that doesn't support the `-W` option, you can also use this:

```
host desktop
   ProxyCommand ssh -x -a -q myusername@connectedNode nc %h 22
```

Comment: Wow, I'm really glad you added that "very old ssh" line, because my situation required it. Thank you so much, it works perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad!  Of course, the other thing I should have added with the "very old ssh" is that "nc" must be present on your system ... but apparently it is, so ... <whew>!  :)